# Forced damped simple harmonic oscillator

Tags: fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform

Consider the equation of motion of the following forced dampded simple
harmonic oscillator
$$\ddot x + \gamma \dot x + \Omega^2x = f (t)$$
where
f (t) =
e^(iω0t)    if |t| ≤ T
0            otherwise   (3)
with ω0 a known angular frequency.
a) Find fb(ω) the Fourier transform of f(t).
b) By taking the Fourier transform of Eq.(1) show that one obtains
xb(ω) = Gb (ω) fb(ω) (4)
and find the explicit expression of Gb(ω). What can you say about the
inverse transform G(t) of Gb(ω)?
c) Consider now a function f(x) and its Fourier transform fb(k). Introduce
a new function g(x) = f(x − x0). Find its Fourier transform gb(k) in
terms of fb(k).
d) Do the same for a function g(x) = f(λx) with λ ∈ R.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use MathJax to format your equations. More important, tell us what you have tried. Where are you stuck? Note that questions showing no effort tend to be voted down, and are usually closed